Build vcxproj with msbuild and warnings disabled
I have an Visual Studio example project with the purpose to generate compiler warnings. Warnings are enabled in the project settings. I want to build the project on the command line with msbuild and explicitly disable all warnings but msbuild seem to ignore all possible ways to do it. Is there some kind of secret trick to make it work?
Here is what I already tried:

msbuild TestCompile.vcxproj -p:AdditionalOptions="/w"
msbuild TestCompile.vcxproj -p:WarningLevel=0

Just as information, the source file looks like this:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void generateWarnings() {
    // Warning C4101: 'unusedVar': unreferenced local variable
    int unusedVar;
 
    // Warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data
    double d = 3.14;
    int i = d;
 
    // Warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'uninitializedVar' used
    int uninitializedVar;
    printf("Uninitialized variable: %d\n", uninitializedVar);
}
 
int main() {
    generateWarnings();
    return 0;
}

The .vcxproj settings file has the default values in it, which is /W4 for the default Debug|Win32 configuration.
<ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'">
    <ClCompile>
      <WarningLevel>Level4</WarningLevel>
      <SDLCheck>true</SDLCheck>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>WIN32;_DEBUG;_CONSOLE;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <ConformanceMode>true</ConformanceMode>
    </ClCompile>
</ItemDefinitionGroup>


Per the documentation for 'WarningLevel' for the 'CL' task, the value needs to be TurnOffAllWarnings for /W0.
